# How can I retrieve Wiktionary word content?

Tags: dictionary, mediawiki-api, wiktionary

How may Wiktionary's API be used to determine whether or not a word exists?

Comment: Anyone who has read the documentation will see that the API contains nowhere near enough functionality to "retrieve Wiktionary word content". I'd estimate it gets you roughly 1% of the way. You can retrieve raw wiki syntax or parsed HTML and from there you have to do everything yourself. Having said that there might be a very new experimental API that works only on the English Wiktionary.

Comment: Get all Wiktionary articles in individual JSON files here: https://github.com/dan1wang/jsonbook-builder

Comment: An even better parsed JSON version is here: https://kaikki.org/

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The [Wiktionary API](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php) can be used to query whether or not a word exists.

Examples for existing and non-existing pages:

> [`http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=test`](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=test)
>   [`http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=testx`](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=testx)

The first link provides examples on other types of formats that might be easier to parse.

To retrieve the word's data in a small XHTML format (should more than existence be required), request the printable version of the page:

> [`http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=test&printable=yes`](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=test&printable=yes)
>   [`http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=testx&printable=yes`](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=testx&printable=yes)

These can then be parsed with any standard XML parser.

Comment: Thanks; the API itself is not what I was hoping for but the link you provided is what I was looking for.

Comment: Now it accepts additional format parameter for other than xml output like so : https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=test&format=json

Comment: Might not work as you expect though https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_misspellings https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amatuer

Comment: Use: `https://en.wiktionary.org/w/?curid=[page_id]&printable=yes`, to redirect to the XHTML page using `pageid`.

Comment: If you need to fetch the data using the browser, you can use ```https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&origin=*&export&exportnowrap&titles=test``` to avoid CORS-related problems

Comment: How to filter in this API for only English words?

Comment: Use HTTPS with those example. The current http version isn't giving results

Comment: Sadly the printable XHTML seems poorly supported. There's a *no longer supported* warning shown. Also, I found that it gives me invalid XHTML, specifically an unclosed <input> tag. Here's the URL I used: https://en.wiktionary.org/w/?curid=103410&printable=yes , alternatively: https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=test&printable=yes

Comment: I've been playing with this myself. I think, if you want to check whether a word is valid in English, you want to use `https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=categories&titles=`WORDS`%7C`TO`%7C`CHECK`&clcategories=Category%3AEnglish%20lemmas%7CCategory%3AEnglish%20non-lemma%20forms%7CCategory%3AEnglish%20eye%20dialect`. Then, "valid in English" means a result that has the category "English lemmas" or "English non-lemma forms" but doesn't have the category "English eye dialect". However the set of words meeting these criteria may still be overly broad for many uses.

Answer (score 47):

**2024 UPDATE!**

It seems that a new MediaWiki REST API has appeared since I last played with this stuff. And the biggest news is that it includes [a method to get definitions from the English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/api/rest_v1/#/Page%20content/get_page_definition__term_)!

> **`/page/definition/{term}`**
> Get term definitions based on Wiktionary content.
> Experimental end point providing term definitions extracted from Wiktionary content. Currently, only English Wiktionary is supported. See [this wiki page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Apps/Wiktionary_definition_popups_in_the_Android_Wikipedia_Beta_app) for background and considerations for further development.
>
> Stability: [stable](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Product/Wikimedia_Product_Infrastructure_team/API_endpoint_stability_policy#Stable)
>
> Please follow [wikitech-](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/wikitech-l)l or [mediawiki-api-announce](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce) for announcements of breaking changes.

---

**Old answer**

There are a few caveats in just checking that Wiktionary has a page with the name you are looking for:

**Caveat #1**: All Wiktionaries including the English Wiktionary actually have the goal of including every word in every language, so if you simply use above API call you will know that the word you are asking about is a word in at least one language, but not necessarily English: http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=dicare

**Caveat #2**: Perhaps a redirect exists from one word to another word. It might be from an alternative spelling, but it might be from an error of some kind. The API call above will not differentiate between a redirect and an article: http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=profilemetry

**Caveat #3**: Some Wiktionaries including the English Wiktionary include "common misspellings": http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=fourty

**Caveat #4**: Some Wiktionaries allow stub entries which have little or no information about the term. This used to be common on several Wiktionaries but not the English Wiktionary. But it seems to have now spread also to the English Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%99%B6%E7%90%83 (permalink for when the stub is filled so you can still see what a stub looks like: https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%E6%99%B6%E7%90%83&oldid=39757161)

If these are not included in what you want, you will have to load and parse the wikitext itself, which is not a trivial task.

Comment: What I really wanted to do was take a full dump of the data on one of the non-English Wikitionary sites, and then turn the contents into something I could use locally.  It seems silly now, but I was hoping that I could request the list of all words, and then pull down their defitions/translations one at a time as needed.

Comment: The fix to Caveat #2 is simple: add `&prop=info` to the query and check the response for `redirect` attribute.

Comment: @svick: Yes it's true #2 is easier to circumvent when using the API but these basic caveats also cover trying to parse the [Wiktionary data dump files](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/), even though this question doesn't ask about that approach.

Answer (score 24):

You can download a dump of [Wiktionary data](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/).  There's more information in the [FAQ](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/Wiktionary:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary).  For your purposes, the [definitions dump](https://web.archive.org/web/20140219152432/http://toolserver.org:80/%7Eenwikt/definitions/) is probably a better choice than the XML dump.

Comment: Those dump files are massive, and it's unclear which ones to download (all of them?). Probably not what most people are looking for it they just want to programmatically lookup a handful of words.

Comment: I explain which file to download - i.e. the definitions dump (the directory from my link is just different versions of the same file), and yes, if you programmatically want to look up words this is ideal.  If you can guarantee the program will be executed only online, there are other options, but nevertheless I'm answering this part of the original question: "Alternatively, is there any way I can pull down the dictionary data that backs a Wiktionary?"

Comment: Definitions dump link is no longer available.

Answer (score 13):

To keep it really simple, extract the words from the dump like this:

```
bzcat pages-articles.xml.bz2 | grep '<title>[^[:space:][:punct:]]*</title>' | sed 's:.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*:\1:' > words
```

Comment: how do I get a copy of pages-articles.xml.bz2?

Comment: It's just a generic name I used to describe the dumps of the form `LANGwiktionary-DATE-pages-articles.xml.bz2` . Go to [link](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html), then click `LANGwiktionary` (LANG e.g. 'en', 'de'...).

Comment: That's great, thanks! If you want to get the words with a dash or space in it, you should use: ``bzcat pages-articles.xml.bz2 | grep '<title>\(.*\)</title>' | sed 's:.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*:\1:' > words``

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Python, you can use [WiktionaryParser](https://github.com/Suyash458/WiktionaryParser) by Suyash Behera.

You can install it by

```
pip install wiktionaryparser
```

Example usage:

```
from pprint import pprint
from wiktionaryparser import WiktionaryParser
parser = WiktionaryParser()
word = parser.fetch('test')
pprint(word)
another_word = parser.fetch('test', 'french')
pprint(another_word)

# features
parser.set_default_language('french')
parser.exclude_part_of_speech('noun')
parser.include_relation('alternative forms')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the *revisions* API:

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=test&rvslots=*&rvprop=content&formatversion=2

Or the *parse* API:

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=test&prop=wikitext&formatversion=2

More examples are provided in the [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Get_the_contents_of_a_page).

Comment: You can also add `&format=json` to the urls to have a formatted response.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned earlier, the problem with this approach is that **Wiktionary provides the information about all the words of all the languages**. So the approach to check if a page exists using Wikipedia API won't work because there're a lot of pages for non-English words. To overcome this, **you need to parse each page to figure out if there's a section describing the English word**. Parsing wikitext isn't a trivial task, though in your case it's not that bad. To cover almost all the cases you need to just check if the wikitext contains the `English` heading. Depending on the programming language you use, you can find some tools to build an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from wikitext. This will cover most of the cases, but not all of them because Wiktionary includes some common misspellings.

As an alternative, you could try using [Lingua Robot](https://www.linguarobot.io) or something similar. Lingua Robot parses the Wiktionary content and provides it as a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API. A non-empty response means that the word exists. Please note that, as opposed to Wiktionary, the API itself doesn't include any misspellings (at least at the moment of writing this answer). Please also note that the Wiktionary contains not only the words, but multi-word expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try JWKTL out. I just found out about it ;)

- *[Wiktionary API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquitous_Knowledge_Processing_Lab#Wiktionary_API)*
- http://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/software/jwktl/

Comment: The citation that you refer to is broken. Here is a link to the JWKTL page http://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/software/jwktl/. It's not really what I believe the OP is looking for though.

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a genetic page,  *[Welcome to the Ubiquitous Knowledge Processing (UKP) Lab!](https://www.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/ukp/ukp_home/index.en.jsp)*.

Comment: The Wikipedia reference leads to *[Extracting lexical semantic knowledge from Wikipedia and Wiktionary](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2008/pdf/420_paper.pdf)* and *"...JWKTL (Java-based WiKTionary Library)..."*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start to parsing etymology and pronunciation data:

```javascript
function parsePronunciationLine(line) {
  let val
  let type
  line.replace(/\{\{\s*a\s*\|UK\s*\}\}\s*\{\{IPA\|\/?([^\/\|]+)\/?\|lang=en\}\}/, (_, $1) => {
    val = $1
    type = 'uk'
  })
  line.replace(/\{\{\s*a\s*\|US\s*\}\}\s*\{\{IPA\|\/?([^\/\|]+)\/?\|lang=en\}\}/, (_, $1) => {
    val = $1
    type = 'us'
  })
  line.replace(/\{\{enPR|[^\}]+\}\},?\s*\{\{IPA\|\/?([^\/\|]+)\/?\|lang=en}}/, (_, $1) => {
    val = $1
    type = 'us'
  })
  line.replace(/\{\{a|GA\}\},?\s*\{\{IPA\|\/?([^\/\|]+)\/?\|lang=en}}/, (_, $1) => {
    val = $1
    type = 'ga'
  })
  line.replace(/\{\{a|GA\}\},?.+\{\{IPA\|\/?([^\/\|]+)\/?\|lang=en}}/, (_, $1) => {
    val = $1
    type = 'ga'
  })
  // {{a|GA}} {{IPA|/ˈhæpi/|lang=en}}
  // * {{a|RP}} {{IPA|/pliːz/|lang=en}}
  // * {{a|GA}} {{enPR|plēz}}, {{IPA|/pliz/|[pʰliz]|lang=en}}

  if (!val)
    return

  return { val, type }
}

function parseEtymologyPiece(piece) {
  let parts = piece.split('|')
  parts.shift() // The first one is ignored.
  let ls = []
  if (langs[parts[0]]) {
    ls.push(parts.shift())
  }
  if (langs[parts[0]]) {
    ls.push(parts.shift())
  }
  let l = ls.pop()
  let t = parts.shift()
  return [ l, t ]
  // {{inh|en|enm|poisoun}}
  // {{m|enm|poyson}}
  // {{der|en|la|pōtio|pōtio, pōtiōnis|t=drink, a draught, a poisonous draught, a potion}}
  // {{m|la|pōtō|t=I drink}}
  // {{der|en|enm|happy||fortunate, happy}}
  // {{cog|is|heppinn||lucky}}
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/ebce876b874a522f89e4d5ca44f6cc6c) is a gist with it more fleshed out.

Comment: thanks, tried to run it inside browser devtools console. what is `langs`?

Comment: updated with a gist, `langs` is a few thousand lines, too big for SO.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own open source [Wiktionary API project](https://github.com/Vuizur/ultimate-dictionary-api). It is based on the [wiktextract](https://github.com/tatuylonen/wiktextract) data and in general has much more information than the official API: For example IPAs, etymology information, canonical forms of words (describing stress in many languages, for example), translation tables.

It also not only contains information from the English Wiktionary, but 6 different Wiktionaries, and can translate any language pair, so for example from French to Czech.

(I currently have it hosted, but can't make any guarantees about uptime etc., but each one can easily self-host if needed).