# Identify Random Strings in Python

Tags: string, python-2.7, dictionary, random

I'm trying to identify random strings from list of strings in python, 
I want to read each word and be able to say if it is random or if it is a meaningful word.The words could be formed by english characters and also programmatically meaningful words like com, java, python etc should be identified.

Other than storing all the english words in a file and comparing them, are there any solution or existing code library already present ?

I know there aren't easy ways to find randomness , any other simple methods or suggestions are also welcome.

ex - rrstm 
     asdfsa
     qmquas

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`PyEnchant`](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a word is an English word with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `pyenchant`.Install it using `pip`

```
sudo pip install pyenchant
```

Then import it.

```
In [1]: import enchant

In [2]: d = enchant.Dict("en_US")

In [3]: d.check("Hello")
Out[3]: True

In [4]: d.check("Helo")
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: But enchant doesn't identify program related words , is there a workaround for this ? ex:                                                                     >>> d.check("java")
False

Answer (score 0):

You can you use wordnik api for comparing the string and checking whether it returns a meaning or no definition found.