# Dictionary of technical terms in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, language-features

I'm looking for a dictionary of technical/engineering terms, ideally covering all disciplines (from computer science to chemical engineering).

I know of [this dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789057/2708484), but I don't think it covers technical terms such as "k-means" and "b-tree".

Are there any good alternatives or solutions to this problem? Thank you!

Comment: "k-mean" is a term from the world of statistics/probability. "b-tree" is a term from the world of algorithms/graphs. There is no "magic" dictionary that can make terminology taken from different worlds - clear. Search wiki for each term separately - no easy alternatives AFAIK.

Comment: For finding the meaning of technical terms, I always use wikipedia. Quick search yields [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and [b-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), which should have all the information you are looking for. I only use proper dictionaries for finding translations or linguistic details (gender, plural, conjugations) about words.

Comment: Thank you! Wikipedia seems like the simplest alternative with endpoints like these `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=quicksort` , since downloading all of those terms might require too much memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is an [Academic Vocabulary Corpus](http://www.academicvocabulary.info/compare.asp) which has around ~120 million words.

  ```
  History (14.3 million words)
  Education (8.5)
  Law and political science (12.5)
  Social Science (16.7)
  Humanities (11.1)
  Philosophy, religion, psychology (12.5)
  Science and technology (22.8)
  Medicine and health (9.7)
  Business and finance (12.8)
  ```
- There is also the [Hong Kong Engineering Corpus](http://rcpce.engl.polyu.edu.hk/HKEC/) with around ~ 9 million words.
- The [Coruna Corpus](http://www.udc.gal/grupos/muste/corunacorpus/index.html) also contains words from various scientific, and engineering fields.

You might want to check these out.