# Differ word vs non-word with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

After lemmatization of text I have a list of lemmas. For each element of this list I would like to figure out is it a word ("cat", "dog", "go", "red") or non-word (".","rand_yh4jhdf","'''","100x200","42,44,46","22:00","xxx___BATMAN___xxx").
Is this problem have a simple solution?
How can I differ word vs non-word with Python and NLTK?

UPD. (for the question what a word is) I want to clear my list from total garbage. Remove what is totally not a word. Don't touch complicated edge cases.

Comment: How do you define a word ? Is it something that exists in the dictionary? Or rather something that consists of letters and not numbers or punctuation ? In the second case "jklsddjladajjlk" would be classified as a word. But in the first it wouldn't as you can't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: I don't have the strict definition for a word. A word is what a word for average person. Looks like my problem have no simple solution.

Comment: If you expect English words there maybe this solution would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python . If you just want to check if it doesn't have numbers and punctuation and do have vocals (each word has vocals, right?) you could just write simple tests for that (regex?).

Answer (score 0):

The following would only returns strings without numbers and punctuation:

```
import re
test = [".","rand_yh4jhdf","''","100x200","42,44,46","22:00","xxx___BATMAN___xxx", "dog", "cat", "computer"]

words = [word for word in test if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]*$", word)]
print(words)
```

output:

```
['dog', 'cat', 'computer']
```