# How to check to see if a string is contained in any english word?

Tags: python, nlp, pyenchant

Going off of this link: [How to check if a word is an English word with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python)

Is there any way to see (in python) if a string of letters is contained in any word in the English language? For example, fun(wat) would return true since "water" is a word (and I'm sure there are multiple other words that contain wat) but fun(wayterlx) would be false since wayterlx is not contained in any English word. (and it is not a word itself)

Edit: A second example: d.check("blackjack") returns true but d.check("lackjac") returns false, but in the function I am looking for it would return true since it is contained in some english word.

Comment: what is the problem with solution from linked question?

Comment: It is saying that if I want to check to see if a string is an english word, where as I want to see if a string is a word OR is contained in any word.

Comment: The question you linked provides an answer to this post. What part of that other answer is unsuitable enough to warrant your posting an intentional duplicate of that same question?

Comment: How is that an answer to my question? d.check("blackjack") returns true but d.check("lackjac") returns false, where as in the function I want it would return true since it is contained in some english word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789057/5997596) to the linked answer.

We can define next utility function using [`Dict.suggest`](https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant/blob/master/enchant/__init__.py#L655-L668) method

```
def is_part_of_existing_word(string, words_dictionary):
    suggestions = words_dictionary.suggest(string)
    return any(string in suggestion
               for suggestion in suggestions)
```

then simply

```
>>> import enchant
>>> english_dictionary = enchant.Dict("en")
>>> is_part_of_existing_word('wat', words_dictionary=english_dictionary)
True
>>> is_part_of_existing_word('wate', words_dictionary=english_dictionary)
True
>>> is_part_of_existing_word('way', words_dictionary=english_dictionary)
True
>>> is_part_of_existing_word('wayt', words_dictionary=english_dictionary)
False
>>> is_part_of_existing_word('wayter', words_dictionary=english_dictionary)
False
>>> is_part_of_existing_word('wayterlx', words_dictionary=english_dictionary)
False
>>> is_part_of_existing_word('lackjack', words_dictionary=english_dictionary)
True
>>> is_part_of_existing_word('ucumber', words_dictionary=english_dictionary)
True
```

Comment: This works in most cases, but there could be false negatives.. The string `"xylo"` is an example. This function would return `False` in the suggested answer as no word similar to `"xylo"` suggested by `.suggest(string)` contains that string, but the word xylophone contains that string. This suggested answer can only be trusted when it returns `True` but not when it returns `False`