# Find 'modern' nltk words corpus

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I'm building a text classifier that will classify text into topics.

In the first phase of my program as a part of cleaning the data, I remove all the non-English words. For this I'm using the **nltk.corpus.words.words()** corpus. The problem with this corpus is that it removes 'modern' English words such as Facebook, Instagram etc. Does anybody know another, more 'modern' corpus which I can replace or union with the present one?

I prefer nltk corpus but I'm open to other suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably more relevant than the marked "duplicate": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python

Answer (score 1):

Rethink your approach. Any collection of English texts will have a "long tail" of words that you have not seen before. No matter how large a dictionary you amass, you'll be removing words that are not "non-English". And to what purpose? Leave them in, they won't spoil your classification.

If your goal is to remove non-English text, do it at the sentence or paragraph level using a statistical approach, e.g. ngram models. They work well and need minimal resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Wikipedia, but it's pretty time consuming to tokenize the entirety of it. Fortunately, it's been done for you already. You could use a [Word2Vec model](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) trained on 100 billion words of wikipedia and just check if the word is in the model.

I also found this [project](https://github.com/chrisjmccormick/inspect_word2vec) where Chris made text files of the 3 millions word vocabulary of the model.

Note that this project's list of words doesn't contain some stop words, so it'd be a good idea to find the union of your list from nltk and this one.