# How do I detect whether a string with no whitespace has any English words?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example,

```
text = 'huwefggthisisastringhef'
```

I'd like to return a *True* or *False* depending on the string. E.g.

```
if detectEnglish(text) == True:
    print('contains english')
```

Comment: Try a simpler question first: how would you determine whether a string *is* an English word?

Comment: Not sure if this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python

Comment: To detect the language which is used in a string, you can try this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at text files with dictionarys and pyenchant but no idea how to actually split it in a way to check whether it is a word

Comment: You could start from testing all possible substrings

Comment: I think you should look at `wordlists dictionary` which have list of all commonly used words and then match them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finds all english words at least three characters long in text

```
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict('en_US')

text = 'huwefggthisisastringhef'
l = len(text)

for i in range(l):
    for j in range(i+3, l+1):
        if d.check(text[i:j]):
            print(text[i:j])
```

Does that by testing all posible substrings (only 231 combinations for 23-chars-long string).

Comment: Here is a one-liner that put all matches in a list (based on your example): **[text[i:j] for i in range(l) for j in range(l+1) if len(text[i:j]) >=3 and d.check(text[i:j])]**

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better methods to do this but if you don't need any information about the words that will be found you can do this.

[This](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) project on Github has over 466K words in a simple text file, you [open](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) the text file read it's content into memory and do [look up](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for combination of letters.

If you wanted to you can sort this file into multi-dimensional dictionaries but to be honest if the text is very random it may be very computationally hungry.

I hope this answer was a bit helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A [trie regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742810/speed-up-millions-of-regex-replacements-in-python-3/42789508#42789508) could help you. You could filter the wordbook by length first, in order to avoid matching `['h', 'u', 'we', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'this', 'is', 'as', 't', 'ring', 'he', 'f']`:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import re
from trie import Trie

with open('/usr/share/dict/american-english') as wordbook:
    english_words = [word.strip().lower() for word in wordbook if len(word.strip()) >= 3]

trie = Trie()
for word in english_words:
    trie.add(word)
test_word = "huwefggthisisastringhef"
print(re.findall(trie.pattern(), test_word))
# ['this', 'string']
```

It takes a few seconds to create the regex but the search itself is extremely fast, and should be more efficient than simply looping over every substring.

```
print(re.findall(trie.pattern(), "sdgfsdfgkjslfkgjsdkfgjsdbbqdsfghiddenwordsadfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdtqtrwerthg"))
# ['hidden', 'words']
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer here is a minor modification I thought could be valuable to share:

```
import enchant

d = enchant.Dict('en_US')
text = 'huwefggthisisastringhef'
l = len(text)
words = {text[i:j]:range(i,j) for i in range(l) for j in range(l+1) if len(text[i:j]) >=3 and d.check(text[i:j])}

print(words)
```

Returns a dictionary with the words and the ranges. Can for instance be used to check which words interesect and so on.

```
{'this': range(7, 11), 
'his': range(8, 11), 
'sis': range(10, 13), 
'string': range(14, 20), 
'ring': range(16, 20)}
```