# How to check for English words in a list

Tags: python, shared-libraries, nltk

I'm trying to check and see if a word is an English word. Not sure if this is the best way to do it, any advice?  It doesn't want to work.

```py
from nltk import wordnet

word_to_test = input("Please enter a word: ")
if not wordnet.synsets(word_to_test):
    print("FALSE")
    #not english word
else:
    print("TRUE")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: "It doesn't want to work" is not a problem specification.  Your posted code doesn't ran as given: at least one syntax error, and it stalls awaiting input.

Comment: I tried running the code and got `AttributeError: module 'nltk.stem.wordnet' has no attribute 'synsets'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a word is an English word with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python)

Comment: The `enchant` package mentioned in the possible duplicate, is not longer maintained, however, there are other methods mentioned as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use the following code:

- `from nltk.corpus import wordnet` with `wordnet.synsets` did not successfully identify English words.

  - All of the words in `word_list` identified as `True`
- Successfully identifying an English word, depends on the dictionary in use.

```py
from nltk.corpus import words

def check_words(word_list: list):
    for word in word_list:
        print(word in words.words())

word_list = ['poisson', 'stark', 'nihongo', 'abstract', 'pedo']
```

#### Output:

```py
check_words(word_list)

False
True
False
True
False
```