# I want to be able to enter a word via an input, return true if the word contains english and false if it doesn't

Tags: python, function, if-statement, syntax, isalpha

## I have written this code to ask for an input and then check if that word is english. If yes return true, if not return false.

```
def onlyEnglishLetters(word):
     word = (input("Enter word here: "))
 if word.isalpha():
    return true
return false
```

output = SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: You need an [else statement](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp).

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python)
(Sorry for the answer but I cant comment yet)

Comment: Random Davis - can you show how i would do that please

Comment: Your indentation is messed up. Please correct it. Also, note that the rule is to use 4 spaces as indent. Respect it, it will make your code easier to read.

Comment: @RandomDavis There is no need for an `else`, the problem is that `return` here is outside of the function because of the messed up indentation.

Comment: @ Thierry Lathuille - I Have indented the return 4 spaces or am I not doing it right?

Comment: Don't think so their is no output the complier simply skips past this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
def onlyEnglishLetters():
    word = (input("Enter word here: "))
    if word.isalpha():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Your original code creates an error because the second return statement is outside of the function. By putting it in an else statement it becomes a part of the function.

You don't need to have 'word' as an argument in the function because you set the value with the input statement.

Also, this will not print the word 'True' or 'False', it only returns that value.

Edit:

If you want the code to print `True` or `False` then this is what you should do:

```
def onlyEnglishLetters():
    word = (input("Enter word here: "))
    if word.isalpha():
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

onlyEnglishLetters()
```

Comment: That seems to work, but then when I tried running the code their is no output, could there be any reason for this?

Comment: @james we have no idea what output you're expecting or how you're trying to get the output. If you want to be able to call `onlyEnglishLetters()` and have it output `True` or `False`, you have to put a `print()` _somewhere_.

Comment: Yes, it only returns the value of true or false. If you want it to print output the value change 'return True' to 'print("True")'. And you need to call the function after you define it.

Comment: Im expecting the code to ask me to input a word and the check if that word is true or false then return true or false

Comment: If you change the return statements to be print statements and then call the function (type `onlyEnglishLetters()` on a separate line after the function definition) it should work.