# how to check if a input is a valid english word using pydictionary

Tags: python, pydictionary

I thought about using

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

word = input("enter a word: ")
dictionary = PyDictionary(word)

check = dictionary.getMeanings()

print(check)
input("press enter to exit")
```

Comment: Do you have a question regarding your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you *have* to use `PyDictionary` you can check the meaning of a word and wrap the return in a `bool` function:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictonary
dictionary = PyDictionary()
valid_word = bool(dictionary.meaning("hdaoij")) # False
valid_word = bool(dictionary.meaning("hello")) # True
```

or

```
valid_word = bool(dictionary.meaning(input("enter a word: ")))
```

Otherwise, I would use the `check` function in `enchant`, in @RoadJDK's answer

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post a while ago:
[How to check if a word is an English word with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python)

```
>>> import enchant
>>> d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
>>> d.check("Hello")
True
>>> d.check("Helo")
False
>>> d.suggest("Helo")
['He lo', 'He-lo', 'Hello', 'Helot', 'Help', 'Halo', 'Hell', 'Held', 'Helm', 
'Hero', 
"He'll"]
>>>
```

Comment: i had a question what do >>> do

Comment: If you go to your terminal or cmd shell and enter `python` or `python3`, you get an interactive Python Console where you can run python code line by line. `>>>` simply just represents the code @RoadJDK has entered in the console and the lines which didn't start with `>>>` are the outputs of the code entered.