# How to generate all anagrams of a given word in Python

Tags: python, anagram

I want to code a function in Python returning all possible anagrams of a word given. Only words of the English language are considered as such.

However, up to now, I only managed to generate all permutations of a word.

```
import itertools

def anagrams(word):
    letters = list(word)
    perms = itertools.permutations(letters)
    return [''.join(p) for p in perms]
```

How can I efficiently check and filter for valid English words now?

Comment: Lookup a dictionary, that's the only way.

Comment: By the way, your code has a major flaw.

Comment: You can use `PyEnchant` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789057/17200348) to check if a string is a valid English word.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am quite new to coding... Could you specify what my flaw is, please?

Comment: @YvesDaoust What flaw do you see exactly? The code seems perfectly fine, albeit the function just returns all possible permutations.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal how many different "anagrams" should `foo` have?

Comment: @slothrop What exactly is your question?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal is it a flaw that `anagrams('foo')` includes (for example) `'ofo'` twice in the result?

Comment: @slothrop I see now! Yes, that is actually a flaw and should be resolved using a set. Would have been nice if YvesDaoust would have clarified that.

Comment: I saw two things I could improve with the aid of stroxx's answer. First, my code is case-sensitive. Second, I did not think about duplicates. Are there more things? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

First you need an English dictionary in Python. I usually use nltk even though there might be better packages. You can install the dictionary of the package by

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
```

and then a slight adjustment of your code yields what you want:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
import itertools

# words.words() is list, for faster runtime
word_set = set(words.words())

def anagrams1(word):
    letters = list(word.lower())
    perms = itertools.permutations(letters)
    word_lst = [''.join(p) for p in perms]
    ana_lst = set(w for w in word_lst if w in word_set)
    return ana_lst
```

For example,

```
anagrams1('sink')
>>> {'inks', 'sink', 'skin'}
```

Edit thanks to Kelly Bundy: A far better runtime can be achieved by a different algorithm, that is checking for every correct word if it is an anagram of the input.

```
def anagrams2(word):
    word_sorted = sorted(word)
    ana_lst = set(w for w in words.words() if sorted(w)==word_sorted)
    return ana_lst
```

Comment: Much better with the set now. But long words like "permutations" still take a long time.

Comment: @KellyBundy You are right. It even produces a memory error on my computer. Do you see any ways to improve the runtime/used memory space?

Comment: Different algorithm. Go through the nltk words and check whether they're anagrams of the input word.

Comment: You *could* improve the first one, in particular by not building a *list* of all permutations. `word_set.intersection(map(''.join, itertools.permutations('permutations')))` runs without issue in ~2 minutes for me. But it's just an inferior approach anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Your method is pretty inefficient for long words. Better precompute all anagrams:

- Get an English dictionary and process it as follows:

  - For every word, sort the letters and add to a Python dictionary using the sorted word as the key, and append to the list of words with the same key;
- For a given query word, sort the letters and lookup the Python dictionary.

E.g. the allowed words are `"one"`, `"two"`, `"three"`, `"neo"`. Store as

```
"eno": ["one", "neo"]
"otw": ["two"]
"eehrt": ["three"]
```

Now the anagrams of `"eon" -> "eno"` are `"one"`, `"neo"`.

---

Note that the preprocessed dictionary is only about twice as large as the initial set of words. And the preprocessing time will remain reasonable as all words have to be input to the set/dictionary anyway (sorting the letters can be done fairly efficiently by histogram sort).

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I'd just do one pass through the dictionary to see if the word had the same letters:

```
from collections import Counter
TARGET_WORD = "trace"
target_pattern = Counter(TARGET_WORD.lower())

for word in open("dictionary.txt","rt").read().splitlines():
    if Counter(word.lower()) == target_pattern:
        print(word)
```

If you were to process multiple words, you can preprocess your dictionary:

```
dictionary = [Counter(x.lower()) for x in open("dictionary.txt","rt").read().splitlines()]

for word in word_list:  # word_list is your list of target words.
    if Counter(word.lower()) in dictionary:
        print (word)
```

(Edit: My first preprocessing program tried to make the preprocessed dictionary a set, but tested the code and `Counter`s aren't hashable as @KellyBundy caught right away. A set would probably be more efficient, so you could use `tuple(sorted(Counter(x).items())` for the entries and the comparison, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: @KellyBundy I just tested that code and caught that.  I could make them into sorted tuples, or just not bother `set` ing them...  Good Catch!

Comment: In the second piece of code, what is `word_list`?

Comment: @slothrop  A list of target words, if you wanted to look up multiple anagrams.

Comment: @RufusVS I think then this needs a step then that reconstructs the actual dictionary word. For example, if `word_list = ['hotnyp']`, then the word's counter should get a hit in the dictionary search, but the printed output will be `hotnyp` not `python`.

Comment: But then you don't print the anagrams of the target words, you only print the target words themselves. Maybe even if they *don't* have anagrams, just appear *themselves* in the dictionary.

Comment: LOL!  Stupid me.  That's what I get for doing a fly-by!  Of course you need the anagram word in there.   Or should I say the list of anagram words.  Each dictionary hit in that case should hold the list of words that it applies to.  I may edit that later.  It's dinner time...