# About JWKTL(JAVA) and how to use the same

Tags: java

I want an API in java which would give me the meaning of words. I tried using JWKTL but I am not getting it. Could anyone direct me regarding this. Thank you.

Comment: For more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770547/is-there-an-api-available-to-retrieve-raw-wiktionary-data

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked WordNet?

But if you're interested in Wiktionary, you may consider checking JWKTL alternative: [Wikokit](http://code.google.com/p/wikokit/)