# Wiktionary : Get list of pages for a given word

Tags: wiktionary, georgian

I would like to have a list of pages existing in wiktionary for a given word.
The case : I search the definition of the word მამა (means dad) in georgian. There is no page for this word in the georgian wiktionary so I would like to have a list of all synonyms.

I have searched and made test with this page :

[`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=ids&rvlimit=10&titles=Foo&titles=Foo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=ids&rvlimit=10&titles=Foo&titles=Foo)

Any idea?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for Wiktionary at the dictionary level, only at the wiki level, which is probably not much help. See this question for more details: [How to retrieve Wiktionary word content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770547/is-there-an-api-available-to-retrieve-raw-wiktionary-data?rq=1)

So there is no API that will allow you to query for synonyms or even to query for Georgian language entries or data.

You can fetch Wiktionary pages either in raw wikitext or in HTML, and you can download entire database dumps in an XML format, which you can try to parse from scratch.

One thing that will help in the case of Georgian is that is has a unique alphabet so the vast majority of Wiktionary entries in the Georgian script will be for the Georgian language. (But there are also a very small number of entries for words in Laz, Mingrelian, Old Georgian, and Svan which will also use the Georgian script.)