# How can I look up an english dictionary in python?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, nlp, nltk

I am developing a Python program in order to find the etymology of words in a text. I have found out there are basically two options: parsing an online dictionary that provides etymology or using an API. I found this reply here but I don't seem to understand how to link the Oxford API with my Python program.

Can anyone explain me how to look up a word in an english dictionary? Thank you in advance.

Link to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395011/python-module-with-access-to-english-dictionaries-including-definitions-of-words)

> Note that while WordNet does not have all English words, what about the Oxford English Dictionary? (http://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/). Depending on the scope of your project, it could be a killer API.
>   Have you tried looking at Grady Ward's Moby? [link] (http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/).
>   You could add it as a lexicon in NLTK (see notes on "Loading your own corpus" in Section 2.1).

```html
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
corpus_root = '/usr/share/dict'
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
```

```html
from nltk.corpus import BracketParseCorpusReader
corpus_root = r"C:\corpora\penntreebank\parsed\mrg\wsj"
file_pattern = r".*/wsj_.*\.mrg"
ptb = BracketParseCorpusReader(corpus_root, file_pattern)
```

Comment: This is difficult, there is no single source of thruth regarding word definition / etymology / disambiguation, even for english. I think there is a tool for the wiktionary that provides etymology, but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the opensource [`ety`](https://github.com/jmsv/ety-python) package. *Disclosure: I'm a contributor to the project*

It's based on the data used in the research "[Etymological Wordnet: Tracing the History of Words](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~demelo/etymwn/)", which has already been pre-scraped from [Wiktionary](https://www.wiktionary.org/).

Some examples:

```
>>> import ety

>>> ety.origins("potato")
[Word(batata, language=Taino)]

>>> ety.origins('drink', recursive=True)
[Word(drync, language=Old English (ca. 450-1100)),
 Word(drinken, language=Middle English (1100-1500)),
 Word(drincan, language=Old English (ca. 450-1100))]

>>> print(ety.tree('aerodynamically'))
aerodynamically (English)
├── -ally (English)
└── aerodynamic (English)
    ├── aero- (English)
    │   └── ἀήρ (Ancient Greek (to 1453))
    └── dynamic (English)
        └── dynamique (French)
            └── δυναμικός (Ancient Greek (to 1453))
                └── δύναμις (Ancient Greek (to 1453))
                    └── δύναμαι (Ancient Greek (to 1453))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`PyDictionary`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDictionary/1.3.4) May be a Good Option

Comment: But does it provide etymology which I can extract?